# Navigating DOM in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently able to find certain elements using the `findAll` function. Is there a way to navigate to their child?

The code I have is:

```
data = soup.findAll(id="profile-experience")
print data[0].get_text()
```

And it returns a block of text (for example, some of the text isn't spaced out properly)

The DOM looks something like this

```
<div id="profile-experience>
  <div class="module-body>
    <li class="position">
    <li class="position">
    <li class="position">
```

If I just do a `findAll` on `class="position` I get way too much crap back. Is there a way using BeautifulSoup to just find the elements that are `<li class="position">` that are nested underneath `<div id="profile-experience">`

I want to do something like this:

```
data = soup.findAll('li',attrs={'class':'position'})
```

(Where I'm only getting the nested data)

```
d in data:
  print d.get_text()
```

Comment: Perhaps a google search or a look at the docs could help you... just a suggestion.

Comment: Yea, I've been doing that. But I can't seem to make it work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can "chain" the `find*` calls:

```
profile_experience = soup.find(id="profile-experience")

for li in profile_experience.find_all("li", class_="position"):
    print(li.get_text())
```

Or, you can solve it in one go with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for li in soup.select("#profile-experience li.position"):
    print(li.get_text())
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on `for li in data.find_all("li", class="position")`

Comment: @MorganAllen note the `_` after the `class`. It is important.

Comment: Ahh, your'e right :-) Can you explain what that does? That worked

Comment: @MorganAllen it's just that `class` is a reserved word in Python (see more [here in the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)).